# Download a remote file (2GB) using PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, curl, ftp, download

I have a large file (2GB) and I want to download it to server A from server B with PHP.

I tried both FTP and CURL with PHP but without success. it returns a TIMEOUT REQUEST error even if I set_time_limit() with 0 value.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0)

$local_file = 'file.zip';
$server_file = '/www/file.zip';

$conn_id = ftp_connect("ftp.webmashing.com");

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");

if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
echo "There was a problem\n";
}

ftp_close($conn_id);

?>
```

Comment: Is `safe_mode` on? On an aside: I would delegate this to a non-http process if its that large (cronjobs, or gearman workers).

Answer (score 0):

If you are having timeouts uploading a file, you might have a look at [`ftp_pasv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php)

```
bool ftp_pasv ( resource $ftp_stream , bool $pasv )
```

In your case, try this:

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect("ftp.webmashing.com");

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");

ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

When called, set_time_limit() restarts the timeout counter from zero. In other words, if the timeout is the default 30 seconds, and 25 seconds into script execution a call such as set_time_limit(20) is made, the script will run for a total of 45 seconds before timing out.   Please check  the "max_execution_time" directive in php.ini

Comment: Yes, but set_time_limit(0) disables the timeout completely.

Answer (score 0):

If you can (depends on where your php files are executed), you can change the max_execution_time to be more longer.

Now, what I would do instead (still, if you have the rights), is to do it in command line called from the php files. The command line would write the results in a specific file and all you have to do would be to check the content of that file.

Once the result is written (say "0" for success as always in linux), you can do what you want.

On the front end, a little ajax to get the state of the downloading could be usefull too !

But as always, it depends on if you can run shell commands.